# limpiar la pantalla

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola me pueden ayudar con mi código no se muy bien como continuar.

Este es el código que estoy realizando:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class tamagotchi():
    def __init__(self,ws):
        self.ws = ws
        self.hambre = 10
        self.felicidad = 10
        self.salud = 5
        self.ws.title("Tamagotchi")
        self.ws.geometry("400x500")#ancho y largo
        self.ws.config(bg = "grey")
        #----------------------------
        self.mi_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.ws, height=423, width=400)#largo y ancho
        self.mi_canvas.pack()
        #----------------------------
        self.boton1 = tk.Button(self.ws, text = "ALIMENTAR",height = 4, width = 26, bd = 7,command=lambda:self.cambiar_imagen())
        self.boton1.place(x=0,y=423)
        self.boton2 = tk.Button(self.ws, text = "JUGAR", height = 4, width = 26, bd = 7,command=lambda:self.cambiar_imagen())
        self.boton2.place(x=201,y=423)
        
        
        self.contador = 0
        self.imagenes = []
        imagen1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('1.jpg'))
        imagen2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('DCL1.png'))
        imagen3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('DCL2.png'))
        self.imagenes.append(imagen1)
        self.imagenes.append(imagen2)
        self.imagenes.append(imagen3)
        self.imagen_en_canvas = self.mi_canvas.create_image((0,0),image=self.imagenes[self.contador], anchor="nw")
        
        
    

    def cambiar_imagen(self):
        self.contador+=1
        if self.contador == len(self.imagenes):
            self.contador=0
        self.mi_canvas.itemconfig(self.imagen_en_canvas,image=self.imagenes[self.contador])
        print("Imagen cambiada")
    

import tkinter as tk
ws = tk.Tk()
mascota = tamagotchi(ws)
ws.mainloop()
```

Mi duda es como puede hacer para colocar una etiqueta y una caja de texto al principio, recoger los datos y después limpiar la pantalla para que ejecute el programa principal.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Consulta [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683274/how-to-close-a-current-window-and-open-a-new-window-at-the-same-time), te servirá. Lo que encontrarás en en enlace es como cerrar la ventana que tienes abierta y abrir otra. Aplicalo a tu código

Comment: @Alexci no es necesario cerrar la ventana y abrir otra. Puedes eliminar o destruir cada widget individualmente con widget.destroy().

Answer (score 0):

una idea que te puedo recomendar es usar el widget TopLevel que te ayuda a abrir una nueva ventana, te comparto este [enlace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm) para que sea tu punto de partida.

Realmente es una solución que puede ayudarte y muy amigable de implementar.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).